# how can pass Date object to mongo database, it convert as Int64 after pass mongo database. how can do that using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, date, int, pymongo

```
 created_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(pathName).st_ctime) # Gate created date time   
 tempDict={"image":sourceFileList[i],"created_time":created_time }
```

I use that code to pass Date object to mongo database but it tern to Int64. how can solve this issue.
[change Date to Int64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INWH6.png)

Comment: Are you saying you want it stored in mongo as an Int or as an ISODate? Please clarify.

Comment: ISODate, i need read as Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is a datetime instance, then it will be saved as an ISODate.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime as dt
import os
db = MongoClient()['testdatabase']
random_file = 'c:\\windows\system.ini'
created_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(random_file).st_ctime) # Gate created date time
db.testcollection.insert_one({'image':'image' ,'created_time': created_time })
```

Gives, in mongo shell:

```
> db.testcollection.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5da469d44cf839072f40c325"),
        "image" : "image",
        "created_time" : ISODate("2016-07-16T12:47:50.561Z")
}
```

Comment: what is that random file? if i host system how can use that?

Comment: The random file was just used as an example. You should use your `pathName`. Sorry I didn't explain that in the response.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? What version of python and mongo are you using?

Comment: {"created_time":1570727474002,"modified_time":1570618827469} my out put look like this it's Int64

Comment: i write this all to the json file and then push to mongo database

Comment: mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
mng_db = mng_client['picDB'] # Replace mongo db name
collection_name = 'resultLogIssuesFind' # Replace mongo db collection name
db_cm = mng_db[collection_name]


with open(r'jsonResult.json') as data_file:
    data_json = json.load(data_file)


db_cm.remove()
db_cm.insert(data_json)

Comment: i found that is the issue. i directly send to mongodb